# Вопрос по pjax и yii2, а именно отображение view без перезагрузки

Tags: yii2

Имеется сайт в котором не должно быть перезагрузок (фронтенд по крайней мере). Так вот, не могу найти решения как сделать так, что бы при клике на меню автоматом подгрузилась нужная вьюшка с моделью, но при этом не было перезагрузки страницы.

При попытках использовать pjax контент меняется полностью, т.е. прападает layout и остаётся renderPartial view. Если непонятно, то по другому: Как в layout засунуть меню (например 2 пункта login и signup) и при клике на один из них менялся контент (выводилась view нужная мне).

Из поисков понял что можно вывести в отдельный блок, но не могу найти как

Comment: Вот это решение по-сути немного помогло [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953659/using-pjax-in-yii2-for-updating-a-div] но я не понимаю логики( А именно почему указав id pjax такой же как и у div происходит обновление div? Есть нормальный параметр для связи? Реально ли вообще при нажатии ссылки 'a' с id='a' обёрнутой в пиджак с id='b' отобразить результат в div с id='c'

Answer (score 1):

Ура! Разобрался наконец-таки со своим вопросом!

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'comments',
    'enablePushState' => false,
    'linkSelector' => '.btn-custom'
]); ?>
    <h2>test</h2>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>


<?= Html::a("Добавить", ['site/preload'], [
    'class' => 'btn-custom',
    'id' => 'refreshButton2'
]) ?>

<?= Html::a("Обновить", ['site/reload'], [
    'class' => 'btn-custom',
    'id' => 'refreshButton',
]) ?>'
```

Суть в том, что можно указать [linkSelector](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html#$linkSelector-detail) и тогда будут отрабатывать без перезагрузок нужные намдействия. Зачем это мне? Для навигации, логинки, регистрации и всего остального без перезагрузок) Не судите строго, только начал учить yii2. Кто может исправить, уточнить либо ещё что-то - всегда посмотрю и учту!